# phonegap jquerymobile issue: lost style when dynamically generating list items

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, html-lists

I'm trying to generate a list dynamically from database. The results can be retrieved, however, jquerymobile style and data-role property seem to be lost. I see an ugly list instead of nicely rendered list:

I've tried to reproduce it using the simplest list item:

In my index.html, I have:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="true" id="thisweekexpenselist"></ul>
```

In the javascript file, I have

```
function getExpenselist_success(tx, results) {
$('#busy').hide();
var len = results.rows.length;
for (var i=0; i<len; i++) {
    var expense = results.rows.item(i);
    $('#thisweekexpenselist').append('<li>Test Simplest</li>'); 
}   
db = null;
```

}

It does not render correctly at all.

Comment: To give you an idea what it looks like, see this picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/25220312/jquery.PNG. The above one is dynamically generated. Forget about the middle two list items, the last item "Test Simplest" is hardcoded into the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try calling `$('#thisweekexpenselist').listview('refresh');` at the end of the getExpenselist_success() function.

Comment: Because your appending data after Jquery Mobile is formatting your list. That method recreates the listview.

Answer (score 1):

This helps:

```
$(document).bind('pagechange', function() {
  $('.ui-page-active .ui-listview').listview('refresh');
});
```